# Query XML by SQL

Tags: sql, xml, enums, db2, ibm-db2

I have an XML column:

```
<xmlList> 
   <XMLEntity> 
      <sug>ACHER</sug>
   </XMLEntity>

  <XMLEntity> 
      <sug>DOA</sug>
   </XMLEntity>
</xmlList>
```

The `sug` can hold only a enum memeber(`ACHER` or `DOA`). I would like to check if there is a `sug` without one of these values.

In this way I get just the sug node where **it is** one of the enum values:

```
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(XMLQUERY ('//xmlList/XMLEntity/sug[.="ACHER"]' passing 
KTOVET ) as char large object) as XXX ,

XMLSERIALIZE(XMLQUERY ('//xmlList/XMLEntity/sug[.="DOA"]' passing 
KTOVET ) as char large object) as YYY   

FROM "TABLE"
```

I would like to get the `sug` nodes where the value **is not** one of the enums value. Possible?
How can I get the sug nodes where its value is "ACHER"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(XMLQUERY ('//xmlList/XMLEntity/sug[.!="ACHER" and .!="DOA"]'  
passing KTOVET ) as char large object) as XXX

FROM "TABLE"
```